# Two-way communication using expect

Tags: linux, expect

I am amidst writing an `expect` script to automate communication between an arduino on `/dev/ttyUSB0` and a `xine` instance on local telnet port 6789. If a keypress is detected on the arduino it will send a line via it's serial output, `button 01 pressed`, `button 2 pressed` and so on. Now, according to the buttons pressed I'd like to tell `xine` to start certain movies.

So far, both communications work on their own, but I need to react to arduino messages with telnet messages, pretty much like this example:

```
User presses key 1.
arduino sends serial line "button 01 pressed"
expect sees this string on /dev/ttyUSB0 and sends "playlist delete all; mrl add movie01.mp4" to xine.
xine then plays this movie while I am asking it for it's status every second.
Once the movie is finished playing, I tell xine to start the "loop" movie and also the arduino to set every output to the idle state.
```

So, basically I am asking for a way two `spawn` to communications (one serial, one telnet) at the same time, `expect`ing different strings on them and programmatically reacting to them (whereas the last part, programmatically reacting, is already done).

Thanks for any help,

```
Christian.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use expect with -i to specify the spawn id which you want communicate to, and set a small timeout value, then you can expect between two processes.

Comment: sounds interesting - would you happen to have a little example from somewhere else that I can look at/read?